# Can I push tableview cells apart from each other?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I want to make my cells separated. Is there a way I can increase the space between tableview cells?
[image]As you can see in this photo, I want to make the cells appear further away from each other. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard for UI and a using custom cell in your tableview, you can achieve your goal by keeping the custom cell's frame bigger than Content View's View.

So, if `cell > Content View's frame = 0, 0, 375, 100`

Please make, `cell > Content View > View's frame = 15, 5, 345, 90`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey, what id im on playgrounds?

Comment: Idea remains the same :) 
In playgrounds, programatically you can keep your cell > view's frame smaller than cell's frame.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the spacing between your cells by making the cell Fram bigger than the content view.

You can do it by the storyboard. Or by using the delegate method estimatedHieghtForRowAt and height for rowAt.